# Having trouble sending variables between functions within separate files - Python and Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.4

I'm having what seems like a basic problem but I'm not sure how to fix it.

I'm making a program which lets the user draw lines over a canvas. I previously had the entire code in one file but since I'm going to add many new tools it seemed a sensible decision to isolate all functions into separate files.
However doing this has resulted in problems. Apologies that there's a lot of code to press through. Here's my code:

Root program: root.py (The one I'm actually running)

```
#Import TKINTER toolset:
from tkinter import *
import starting_variables

#Starting variables:
starting_variables.start_vars()

#Tool width control:
global tool_width
tool_width = Scale(control_panel,from_=1,to=32)

canvas.bind("<Button-1>",line_start_xy)

control_panel.pack(side=LEFT,fill=Y)
tool_width.pack()
wrkspace.pack()
canvas.pack()

#Runs window:
window.mainloop()
```

This file defines all the variables needed from the start: (starting_variables.py)

```
from tkinter import *

def start_vars():
    #Starting variables:
    line_startx = 0
    line_starty = 0
    line_endx = 0
    line_endy = 0
    mouse_x = 0
    mouse_y = 0
    #Main window:
    window = Tk()
    #Workspace and Canvas:
    wrkspace =  Frame(window, bg="blue",width=640,height=480)
    canvas = Canvas(wrkspace,bg="white",width=640,height=480)
    control_panel = Frame(wrkspace,bg="white",width=32,relief=SUNKEN,bd=5)
```

For some reason, when I run the root program is tells me that in line 10 of root.py control_panel has not been defined, but I ran the function which defines it. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: As you declared those variables inside a function definition, they do not exist outside such function. Either you declare each function as `global` inside the definition, or you remove altogether the line with `def` and then in root.py access directly each variable as `starting_variables.tool_width`.

Comment: ...or you add `return control_panel ` to the end of `def start_vars()` and thereby keep your function but avoid using `global`s (they should generally be avoided when you can). Then you could write `ctrl_pnl = starting_variables.start_vars()` and `ctrl_pnl.pack(side=LEFT,fill=Y)` in `root.py`

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand scopes in python. Everything you did in the `start_vars` function is useless to the rest of the program. The `control_panel` only exists in the body of that function. When the function is done, you have NO `control_panel`

Although this is bad programming to begin with, you could try doing something like this:

```
def start_vars():
    #Starting variables:
    line_startx = 0
    line_starty = 0
    line_endx = 0
    line_endy = 0
    mouse_x = 0
    mouse_y = 0
    #Main window:
    window = Tk()
    #Workspace and Canvas:
    wrkspace =  Frame(window, bg="blue",width=640,height=480)
    canvas = Canvas(wrkspace,bg="white",width=640,height=480)
    control_panel = Frame(wrkspace,bg="white",width=32,relief=SUNKEN,bd=5)

    return locals()  # this gives a dictionary containing the local names... you don't have acces to them otherwise.
```

and then, in your `root.py` do this at some point

```
my_vars = starting_variables.start_vars()
```

Then you can get your the  `control_panel` in root.py like this

```
control_panel = my_vars['control_panel']
```

and ONLY AFTER THIS you can use the `control_panel` variable.

Additionally you can do hacks like this

```
my_vars = starting_variables.start_vars()
globals().update(my_vars)
```

But this is a bad advice, and you program is structured badly.

**[EDIT]**
Since you seem a little confused, here's how I would have done this thing:

```
class Application:
    # simple variables (ints, strings, etc) can be initiated here
    line_startx = 0
    line_starty = 0
    ...

    # you should have some arguments here, so as not to hard-code everything, so you can reuse this application class. For example, the widths, heights, colors maybe
    def __init__(self):  
        # In the init, put things that take a little more customization, that need parameterization, or that take longer to execute
        self.window = TK()
        self.workspace = Frame(self.window, bg="blue",width=640,height=480)
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.wrkspace, bg="white", width=640, height=480)
        self.control_panel = Frame(self.wrkspace, bg="white", width=32, relief=SUNKEN, bd=5)
```

This can be in your `starting_variables.py` module
Then, in your `root.py`, you can put

```
from tkinter import *
import starting_variables

#Starting variables:
app = starting_variables.Application()  # here's where you'd pass the heights, widths, and the rest of the parameters.

#Tool width control:
tool_width = Scale(app.control_panel,from_=1,to=32)

app.canvas.bind("<Button-1>",app.line_start_xy)

app.control_panel.pack(side=LEFT,fill=Y)
tool_width.pack()
app.wrkspace.pack()
app.canvas.pack()

#Runs window:
app.window.mainloop()
```

I'm not sure if you're familiar with object-orientation, but this is just the way I'd do it. Your way would totally work in C, but Python just doesn't have global variables as you expected them to be.... everything's an attribute on a module, an object...something.

Why I think the way I wrote the code is better, is because touching functions like `locals`, `globals`, or touching module attributes from other modules is considered bad in Python because it's unexpected. People expect functions to return values, object to hold attributes and methods, classes to describe objects, etc... Sorry If I'm boring you with too much theory man, just hope the explanations help :)

Comment: Thank you for the help. I can't make changes immediately but I will get back to you after I've made the changes you've recommended, I'm relatively new to this kind of thing anyway haha.

Comment: By the way, could you tell me as to why my program is structured badly?

Comment: well badly only in the sense that this pattern you're using is clearly invented by yourself, and i haven't found any projects with do things like this. I could go on and on about object-oriented programming, but the main idea is this: what you tried to do is called magic. it's magic because you're the only one who would expect that invoking your function would create some variables in the local scope. when calling a function, you should expect to get back a result and NOT to modify state (unless connecting to external systems, where you don't have a choice).i modified my answer with an example

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, I'll definitely do some research on scopes and act on the changes you have reccomended.